# Use CAML query based on ID to retrieve a file name?

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, caml-query, spservices

With jquery and spservices, I use `getSelectedItems` to retrieve the IDs of a few documents. Can I have a loop which goes through a caml query for each of those IDs to retrieve the file name (FileLeafRef, I believe)? I've only used caml query within small console applications for a singular item, so I'm not entirely sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve an additional information about selected items:

```
function getSelectedItems(success,error)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //selected list Id
    var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //selected Items Ids
    if(selectedItemIds.length == 0)
        return;

    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var qry = createQueryForSelectedItems(selectedItemIds);
    var result = list.getItems(qry);
    context.load(result);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
       function() {
          success(result);       
       },
       error
    ); 

}



function createQueryForSelectedItems(selectedItemIds){
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var viewXml = "<View> \
                     <Query> \
                       <Where> \
                         <In>  \
                          <FieldRef Name='ID'/> \
                          <Values>";
    for (var idx in selectedItemIds)
    {
        viewXml += "         <Value Type='Counter'>" + selectedItemIds[idx].id + "</Value>";
    }                      
    viewXml+= "            </Values> \
                         </In> \
                       </Where> \
                     </Query> \
                  </View>";
    qry.set_viewXml(viewXml);        
    return qry;               
}


//Usage: print file name of selected items
getSelectedItems(function(items){
    var e = items.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
       var item = e.get_current();
       console.log(item.get_item('FileLeafRef'));
    }
},function(sender,args){
    console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ID' />
         <Value Type='Number'>{YourIdGoesHere}</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
   <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></OrderBy>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='ID' />
   <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
   <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions>
   <ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
   <OptimizeFor>FolderUrls</OptimizeFor>
</QueryOptions>
```

[Check out this link for more details](http://platinumdogs.me/2009/07/21/querying-document-libraries-or-pulling-teeth-with-caml/)

Comment: Is this the proper format to return a set of results? I'm confused on how I would implement this query to store its results into an array or enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to call Caml Query inside loop to get the FileLeafRef here since you already know the IDs of the Documents. You can use [SP.List.getItemById(id)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee658585%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method.Please see below code to give you an idea of how to start with:

```
items = [];   
        function getSetListItem() {
            var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                var list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("DocumentLibraryName");
                for (var i=1;i<=5;i++)//Change this to your loop condition
                {
                var itemDetails = new Object;
                var listItem = list.getItemById(i);
                itemDetails.ListItem=listItem;
                clientContext.load(listItem);
                items.push(itemDetails);
                }
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnLoadSuccess,OnLoadFailed);
            }
        } 
        function OnLoadSuccess() {
              for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {            

                 var itemDetails = items[x];

                 alert(itemDetails.ListItem.get_item('FileLeafRef'));
                 }
        } 

         function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
              alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: I considered going down this path, but I have too many functions that need the file names. With ctx.executeQueryAsync, I can't push the file name variable to a global variable so all of my work with the variable needs to be done inside there. Is the caml query approach not preferred?