# Get multiple list items by respective IDs - Javascript object model / REST API

Tags: javascript, performance, csom

I am developing a custom ribbon action as **Sharepoint hosted app**, where the user can select any number of list items and click on the action. On click of the ribbon action, the app redirects to the app landing page where I can fetch the selected item IDs. Now I need to retrieve the respective list items. One of the crude option is to loop the IDs and fetch the list items which I want to avoid.

I tried the batch processing in Javascript object model - use getitembyid method on each item ID, put the result into an array and call the

context.load(array);

This does not seem to work. I thought of creating a camlquery XML in loop for all list items and execute the query once !!

Any suggestions for better approach ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you haven't specified what error occurs, below is demonstrated how to load multiple list items by their ids:

```
var listTitle = 'Tasks'; //list title
var ids = [1,2,3];  //item ids

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var result = []; //for storing items 
ids.forEach(function(id){
    var item = list.getItemById(id);
    ctx.load(item);
    result.push(item);
});
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  function() {
     result.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item.get_item('Title')); 
     });
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Comment: Ah ! I was trying to load the array of items ! This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it via CAML.

The query should be somewhat like this:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <Value Type='Number'>{FirstID}</Value>
     </Eq>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' />
        <Value Type='Number'>{SecondID}</Value>
     </Eq>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Here's a complete example:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('YourListName');
var ids = [1, 2, 3]; 

//create caml
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
var q = "<View><Query><Where><Or>";
ids.forEach(function (id) {
    q += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + id + "</Value></Eq>";
});
q += "</Or></Where></Query></View>";

query.set_viewXml(q);
var results = list.getItems(query);

ctx.load(results, 'Include(Id, Title)');
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        var listEnumerator = results.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        }
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        //error
    }
);
```

[Here's a similar approach.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/94202/10271)